# How do I describe a linear decresing function in certain years in simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am developing a dynamic Simulink model to describe the flow of a product.

[image]

After using the product (the use box), there is a flow called "waste". 
And this flow will decrease linearly from 40% to 10% of the amount input to the use box from the year 2005 to 2030.

And the question is, how could I describe this linearly decrease? What I am analyzing is the flow from 2005 to 2035, but the decreasing only happens from 2005 to 2030, and after that remains a constant 10%.

Should I use the box Rate Limiter Dynamic? But in this box, how can I define the year range?

In the figure, there is a simple model of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Matlab Function block, in combination with a `clock`: 
[image]

```
function flow_out = fcn(t, flow_in)

    if t >= 2005 && t < 2030
        flow_out = (0.4 - (0.3/25)*(t-2005))*flow_in;
    elseif t >= 2030
        flow_out = 0.10*flow_in;
    else
        flow_out = 0.40;
    end

end
```

[image]